# Does this $(x+y)^2\ge 4xy$ hold for all real $x$ and $y$ - not only for non-negative?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof, discriminant

Does this $(x+y)^2\ge 4xy$ hold for all real $x$ and $y$ - not only for non-negative?

I'm pretty much sure it is:

Suppose above is not true, that is  $(x+y)^2< 4xy$

Then we come to a contradiction $(x-y)^2< 0$, which means that our assumption is false => the opposite is true.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: There is no need to prove by contradiction. You can just rewrite the inequality as $(x-y)^2\ge 0$.

Comment: A direct proof is always better: $0\le (x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy$. 
By adding $4xy$ to both sides
$4xy\le x^2+y^2+2xy = (x+y)2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is right.

I think it's better the following.

Note $$(x+y)^2-4xy=(x-y)^2\geq0$$
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, but I think it can be simplified. In fact, you can rewrite the inequality as:
$$x^2+y^2+2xy-4xy>0\leftrightarrow (x-y)^2>0$$
which is always true $\forall x,y \in R$.

Answer (score 1):

Because ${\left ( (x+ y)^{2}- 4xy \right )}'= 2(x- y)(1- {y}')$, so

$$(x+ y)^{2}- 4xy\geq (y+ y)^{2}- 4y^{2}= 0$$

Comment: Mr. @MichaelRozenberg ? I want to comment one of your own posts..